# Dynamically generate sections by years

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

***What I am currently doing,***

[image]

***What I want,***

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-section">
    <div class="main-section_head">
         <h2> Cricket Match Events</h2>

        <img src="http://lode.nl/images/icon_collapse.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="main-section_body">
        <table id="cricketTable" class="cricket-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Venu Title</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
loadEvents: function (data) {
    var crickekBody = $("#cricketTable tbody").empty();

    if (data && data.length > 0) {
        crickekBody.siblings("thead").show();
        $(data).each(function (i) {
            var row = $("<tr class='cricket-row' data-eid='" + i + "'>" +
                "   <td class='cricket-cell'>" +
                "       <div class='hover' title='Go to Event Site'>" + this.EventTitle + "</div>" +
                "   </td>" +
                "   <td class='cricket-cell'>" +
                "       <span>" + Crick.Utls.getDate(this.EventDate) + "</span>" +
                "   </td>" +
                "   <td class='cricket-cell'>" +
                "       " + Crick.Others.parseStatus(this.Status) +
                "   </td>" +
                "</tr>")
                .appendTo(crickekBody);

            var rowObj = this;

            row.children("td:first").on("click", function () {
                Crick.Utls.openNewTab(rowObj.EventUrl);
            });
        });
    } else {
        crickekBody.siblings("thead").hide();
        Crick.Utls.addAnnotation(crickekBody, "No events details found");
    }
},
```

**CSS**

Find it here in jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jer0nLxs/2/

**I am not sure how to move forward with followings,**

```
    var listOfYears = [];
    $(data).each(function (i) {
        var year = new Date(this.EventDate).getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(year, listOfYears) === -1)
            listOfYears.push(year);
    });
```

**I need to dynamically generate YEARS SECTIONS (collapsible) based on event dates provided in data (which is coming from a service response),** so if I have two events dates,   01/01/2014 & 01/01/2011, then I want to generate two sections, one for Year 2014 and one for Year 2011. and if I only have a event with date 01/01/2015 then I only want to generate one section based on that.

Please note this is part of a much bigger solution, so I can't provide everything because of privacy policies, above code has been modified for privacy reasons. and IE-8 is a must have req. Thanks

Comment: Please note, in picture under "what I want" Year X is just there for example, based on scenario, I only have 2 events of 2015 year so it only going to have Year 2015, I hope i made it clear.

Comment: Format of date is "06/07/2015 09:00:00"

Comment: Is this question about data manipulation, html, css, DOM-JS?